# How to keep quantile lines in ggplot violin chart when using plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to add a bit of interactivity to my ggplot violin charts using the r `plotly` package. Unfortunately, whenever i wrap the plot in `ggplotly`, bits of my chart disappear. Specifically, when creating the violin chart i use the `draw_quantiles` parameter to draw horizontal lines in the chart. These lines appear correctly in ggplot, but they are not present in the plotly output.

Below is a reproducible example. First chart is ggplot containing the desired horizontal lines. Once the ggplot is wrapped in ggplotly function, the horizontal lines disappear:

```
# load the libraries
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# create example data
DT <- data.table(x= rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 1000),
                 y = rpois(3000, lambda = c(2, 3, 5)))

# create violin chart using ggplot
p <- ggplot(DT, aes(x =x, 
               y = y, 
               fill = x)) +
  geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) 

# wrap ggplot in plotly
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Plotly doesn't seem to have an equivalent geometry object: https://plot.ly/r/violin/

An alternative is to overlay a boxplot geom.

```
ggplot(DT, aes(x =x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_violin(alpha=0.7) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.2, fill="white")
```

But plotly ignores the boxplot width, so that's not as pretty as it is in native ggplot2.

So you'll have to use the native plotly syntax to embed the boxplot into the violin more nicely. Consult the link I provided.

EDIT:

If you want to make your life more complicated you can probably manually calculate the position of horizontal line segments to manually draw the quartiles and overlay them separately onto vanilla violins with a grouped line or dumbbells or something like that. Plotly should be able to display line or point geoms. But I think it's more hassle than it is worth for a less elegant result.